# How to interpolate a vector and work with variables (ode45)?

Tags: matlab, vector, interpolation, equations, ode45

I'm working with an ODE model the one I have to put a vector in a variable and then solve it, but I have some parameters which depends on some of the equations of the model, like auxiliar functions/equations but I get this error:

```
Error using Hovorka2004_Prueba>fun
Too many output arguments.

Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   %
ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0,
tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs,
odeFcn, ...

Error in Hovorka2004_Prueba (line 8)
[t,x]=ode45(@fun,tspan,x0);
```

This is what I have so far:

```
function [t,x]=Hovorka2004_Prueba
    tspan=[0;100];
    x0 = [0.1249; 0.0941; 0; 0;0; 0.7665;0.9519; 0.8473];
    global out1
    [t,x]=ode45(@fun,tspan,x0);
    out1=[t,x]
     assignin('base','out1',out1);
     figure
        subplot(2,1,1)
        plot(t,x(:,1));
        subplot(2,1,2)
        plot(t,x(:,5));
    end
    function fun(t,x)
    uu1 = importdata('datossinmodi.mat'); 
    ufun = @(t) interp1(1:length(uu1), uu1, t, 'nearest', 0); 
% Begining of the parameters
      % Constants:
        F01= 0.0097; 
    EGP0= 0.0161;
    k12=0.066;
    DG=0;
    AG=0.8;
    tmaxG=40;
    VG= 0.16;
    tmaxI=55;
    Ke=0.138;
    VI=0.12;
    Ka1=0.006;
    Ka2=0.06;
    Ka3=0.03;
    Kb1= 51.2e-4*Ka1; 
    Kb2= 8.2e-4*Ka2;  
    Kb3= 520e-4*Ka3;  
    % Auxiliar Functions/Equations:
     G=x(1)/VG;
    if G>=4.5
        F01_C=F01;
    else
        F01_C=F01*G/4.5;
    end
    if G>=9
        FR=0.003*(G-9)*VG;
    else
        FR=0;
    end
     UI=x(4)/tmaxI;
     UG=(DG*AG*t*exp(-t/tmaxG))/(tmaxG)^2;
% Model:
  f = @(t,x) [   
          -((F01_C/VG*G)*x(1))+ x(6)*x(1) + k12*x(2) - FR + UG + EGP0*(1-x(8));  %(1)  
          x(6)*x(1)-(k12+x(7))*x(2);             %(2)
          ufun(t)-(x(3)/tmaxI);                  %(3) IN HERE ufun(t) IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO PUT THE VECTOR
          (x(3)/tmaxI)-(x(4)/tmaxI);             %(4)
           UI/VI - Ke*x(5);                      %(5)
          -Ka1*x(6)+ Kb1*x(5);                   %(6)
          -Ka2*x(7)+ Kb2*x(5);                   %(7)
          -Ka3*x(8)+ Kb3*x(5);                   %(8)
          ];
  end
```

How can I make it work? What's wrong with it?

Thanks a lot for your help (:

EDIT: I tried `function dx=fun (t,x)` but it keeps sending an error:

```
>> Hovorka2004_Prueba
Error in Hovorka2004_Prueba>fun (line 21)
uu1 = importdata('datossinmodi.mat');

Error using feval
Output argument "dx" (and maybe
others) not assigned during call to
"C:\Users\AnnieA\Dropbox\Tesis (A.
Olay)\MATLAB Simulations\Lectura de
Vectores\Hovorka2004_Prueba.m>fun".

Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   %
ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0,
tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs,
odeFcn, ...

Error in Hovorka2004_Prueba (line 8)
[t,x]=ode45(@fun,tspan,x0);
```

Also with `function f=fun(t,x)` but it sends this

```
>> Hovorka2004_Prueba
Error using odearguments (line 93)
FUN returns a vector of length 1,
but the length of initial conditions
vector is 8. The vector returned by
FUN and the initial conditions
vector must have the same number of
elements.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0,
tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs,
odeFcn, ...

Error in Hovorka2004_Prueba (line 8)
[t,x]=ode45(@fun,tspan,x0);
```

Comment: The definition of `ufun` and its subsequent use in `f` seems OK at first glance. What do you exactly mean by "haven't been able to make it work"?

Comment: "but I haven't been able to make it work" is not helpful. Edit your question to indicate precisely what is wrong an errors or warnings. Your integration function, `fun`, doesn't return anything. It should return your integrated ODEs. Also, putting `if`/`else` statements in an integration function is usually a bad idea as it make your equations very stiff (at a minimum `ode15s` should be used, but ideally [event detection](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html?refresh=true#f1-669698) should be used).

Comment: And it doesn't seem like a good idea to `importdata` anything inside an integration function: that tends to be evaluated a *lot* of times, so anything time-consuming should be done elsewhere, if possible.

Comment: I wrote there the error I am having, also, the if/else statements are there because that's how their values are staten in the paper I'm working with, and I'm just trying to make a trial with this code before I put into a GUI, thanks

Comment: As @horchler already told you: your function `fun` doesn't return anything, but `ode45` tries to call it as something like `dy=fun(t,y)` with a return value. Hence the error "Too many output arguments".

Comment: I tried it already, but then I get the error 2 (see above)

Comment: What do you think `dx` means? It's a non-existent variable in your code. You probably mean `function dx=fun(t,x)` and in the end of your function `dx=f(t,x)`.......